# Prevent lazy loading in view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a JSON result from a query that looks like this:

```
{  
    "id":1,
    "user_id":"1",
    "message":"Hello, world",
    "created_at":"2016-09-22 00:32:20",
    "updated_at":"2016-09-22 00:32:20",
    "stats": [
        ...
    ]
},
{  
    "id":2,
    "user_id":"1",
    "message":"Hello, world",
    "created_at":"2016-09-22 00:32:20",
    "updated_at":"2016-09-22 00:32:20",
},
{
    ... more results
}
```

Notice that sometimes the result has a `stats` property and sometimes it does not (despite every record having a `stats` relationship). Don't ask why, that's just how I have it set up in the backend.

I want to loop through these results in my view, like this:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    @if (isset($post->stats) && !empty($post->stats)
        {{ $post->stats->total }}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

However, for post `id` 2, the loop will also output the `$post->stats->total` value because it lazy loads the `stats`.

How can I prevent it from lazy loading the `stats` relationship?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That happens because you are accessing `$post->stats`. You can instead check if the `stats` relationship is loaded or not by using the `relationLoaded()` method defined in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    @if ($post->relationLoaded('stats'))
        {{ $post->stats->total }}
    @endif
@endforeach
```